# Raspberry Pi - Increase Blinking Speed LED

Tags: python

I have two LEDs, blue and green. I want to gradually increase the blinking speed of the green LED while the blue LED is also on at the same time for 5 seconds. Here is my code so far.

```
def blink_green():
    blue.on()
    for i in range(5):
      green.toggle()
      time.sleep(0.5)
      green.toggle()
      time.sleep(0.5)
```

To execute this function, this is the code

```
while True:
  blink_green()
```

It somehow works but the green LED is only blinking at a constant rate. Any suggestions on how I can make the green LED blink at an increasing rate?

Comment: `blink_led()` is not the code that executes the above function `blink_green2()`. please revise you're question. also what is `red1` and why is it relevant in the green blink? **also** *also* what is `green2`?

Comment: You must reduce the sleep time. If you want to stick with the 50% duty cycle, maybe parameterize the sleep time: `s_time = 0.5/i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the duration in a variable and decrease the duration in every loop

```
def blink_green2():
    red1.on()
    sleep_duration = 0.5
    for i in range(5):
      green2.toggle()
      time.sleep(sleep_duration)
      green2.toggle()
      time.sleep(sleep_duration)
      sleep_duration -= 0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradually increasing the speed of blinking means that you need to decrease the sleep duration between the blinking. So in the for loop you need to decrease the value of i. so something like this.

```
def blink_green2():
    red1.on()
    for i in range(0,0.5,0.1):
      green2.toggle()
      time.sleep(0.5-i)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the led to blink faster, you could decrease the amount of time the task sleeps. As the loop increases, the value of **i** increases. Try this:

```py
def blink_green2():
    red1.on()
    for i in range(5):
      green2.toggle()
      time.sleep(0.5 - (i / 25))
      green2.toggle()
      time.sleep(0.5 / (i / 25))
```

Do note that you can increase the range number. You can also change what **i** is divided by to make the led blink at a different rate. Call the function the same as before, like this:

```py
while True:
  blink_green2()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```py
def blink_green():
    green2.on()
    delay = 0.5
    for i in range(5):
      green2.toggle()
      time.sleep(delay)
      green2.toggle()
      time.sleep(delay)
      delay -= .1

while True:
    blink_green()
```

> at an increasing rate

it should start with a .5s delay and speed up to a 0s delay